# How to break an egg without making noise?

Tags: food

Sometimes I have to break an egg while my baby daughter is asleep, and since her sleep is very light, the noise breaking an egg usually does (single sharp noise) sometimes wakes her up.

So my question is, how to break an egg silently, without making noise, and yet do it efficiently, without having the shell all mixed with the egg itself?

Comment: Can I ask if your baby wakes up when you cook the egg as well? Having had children, I used to keep the radio on quietly while they fell asleep and as they slept to cover normal household noises so they didn't wake...

Comment: @Bamboo no, problem is only with sharp and sudden noises. Quiet radio won't help, since the sharp noise is louder. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mask the sudden crack of the eggshell behind other, gentler noises.  For example, you could gradually turn on the water in the sink, slowly increase the stream until it's a loud (but gentle) hiss, and then crack the egg during that. The sound should be about the same both in quality and volume, so the eggshell crack won't stand out as a sudden jarring noise.

(Disclaimer: I don't have children, so I don't know if this will be effective or if your daughter will just wake up because of the running water noise.)

Comment: Thanks, actually I often take shower when she sleeps and this doesn't wake her up. Good idea! :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit late to this question, but there's a solution that's non-technical that seems fairly obvious to me.

If you're able to take a shower without waking your daughter then it makes sense that you should be able to move to a separate room, softly close the door, break the egg, and then walk back.

Then you won't need a convoluted method to break your egg, or have to waste water in running a shower to cover the noise.

Answer (score 3):

Drill two holes--one on the top and the other on the bottom of an egg and then blow through one hole to push all the stuff from the other (if you can find a needle-pump [check the video], you can do this with one hole). In this way, not only you make no sound, but you also save the whole intact eggshell for Easter egg decorating.

Keep in mind that most eggs have a air sac at the bottom of them, so it's usually better to blow out the bottom through the top.

I wouldn't say this is efficient, but I assume you are not cracking hundreds of eggs daily. Other than that, this should be the quietest way of getting an egg out of its shell.

This video might be helpful: [How to Blow Out an Egg](https://www.marthastewart.com/969059/how-blow-out-egg)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Lifehacks. This is great, as long as there's a quiet way to drill into the egg. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Crack some eggs the night before, put them in a container, use them in the morning.

Comment: This should work fine.  Put them into a bag, put them in the fridge.  On day of use, just cut the bottom of the bag with a pair of scissors and you're there.

Answer (score 2):

All you gotta do is use a butter knife and lightly hit the egg with it until it cracks enough for you to break it.

Answer (score 1):

The shell of an egg is predominantly calcium carbonate and will thus dissolve in acid. There's a common kids experinebt that involves dissolving the shell of an egg in white vinegar to make it bouncy. Leaving the egg in the vinegar for an extended period also pickles the egg white, making it increasingly rubbery and bouncy

You could experiment with different household acidic liquids (vinegar, lemon juice, soda water) to find the time required to dissolve or weaken the shell sufficiently that it breaks silently or cuts with scissors, without being in the acid for so long that it becomes flavoured (though who knows, you may come to like lemon eggs!) You probably only need to dip one end of the egg rather than immerse the entire thing

You could additionally consider changing how you eat it (I'm presuming you fry, or scramble); boiling an egg then rolling it around in the base of the pan, under the water will quietly break the egg shell into fine pieces, squeezing one end then causes the boiled egg to pop out the other - it's a temporary measure; babies sleeping patterns don't remain fixed for long (in a few month's time things will be different).

There may also be periods where she is in a deep sleep and breaking an egg normally doesn't disturb her. Sleeping runs in cycles, and my experience is that a child's cycle is about 30 mins long whereas an adults is 45 to an hour. People are most susceptible to being woken when in the lighter dreaming phases of sleep